# Plastic bags broken down by soap fumes

Tags: plastics

I've searched online, but have not found anyone that has experienced the same.
I have a 20 gallon plastic tub with a lid.
In it keep plastic shopping bags.
Also had a box of detergent in there.
I witnessed over time, the fumes (I am guessing) from the detergent affected the plastic bags.
The big 20 gallon bin is fine tough.
But a few of the plastic bags turned brittle to the touch and broke down into tiny bits like old dry leaves when I crumple it in my hand.
Just wondering what is happening to the plastic; chemistry wise. Has the breakdown of the plastic been accelerated by the detergent fumes?
Just found it very odd, and if the process can be used to help recycle plastic by breaking it down faster
I still have the bags on hand and can make a video as proof.

Comment: Share pictures please of plastic bags (brand?) and also the name of the detergent. Was it exposed to light or sunlight?